# I need to clean audio from white noise

Tags: windows, audio, noise

I have wmv video with audio which has a lot of static noise from low quality mic. I need a software to filter noise off.

Would like also an equaliser and some other settings to make audio to be what I want.

In fact it is speech which is drawn in the static noise. I need to make it recognisable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Audacity ( http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ ) includes tools that can help clean off white noise, but this isn't "CSI: Miami," thus it's quite possible there is too much noise and not enough signal to make speech recognizable. Good luck!